# Checking if malloc is allocating all memory using pmap

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory

I'm trying to understand the basics of memory mapping.
I wrote the following small program: it allocates some number of bytes passed as an arg, then continually sets the bytes until the program is terminated:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("pid = %d\n", getpid());

    double mb = strtod(argv[1], NULL);
    size_t bytes = 1000 * mb;
    printf("allocating %f mb, or %ld bytes\n", mb, bytes);

    char* ptr = (char*)malloc(bytes);
    printf("allocated at %p\n", ptr);

    size_t i=0;
    while (1) {
        for (i=0; i<bytes; i++) {
            ptr[i] = 'a';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run `./a.out 10000` and then `pmap <pid> -X` for the corresponding `pid`, I find that the ptr starts at `0x7ff9cf753010` but the following is shown for the heap:

```
         Address Perm   Offset Device   Inode  Size   Rss  Pss Referenced Anonymous LazyFree ShmemPmdMapped FilePmdMapped Shared_Hugetlb Private_Hugetlb Swap SwapPss Locked THPeligible Mapping
    559eba856000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0   132     4    4          4         4        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 [heap]
    7ff9cf753000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0  9768  9768 9768       9768      9768        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0
```

I'm confused because the size is 9768, not 10,000. I'm guessing the 132 bits is some kind of header for the heap? Also, the pointer value is not the same ... Would appreciate any kind of clarity on this.

Comment: `mb` is definitely not the right unit for 1000 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

The difference in size you see isn't actually a difference in size like you think, it's due to `k` being used to mean both `1000` and `1024` in combination with `B` for bytes, sometimes `Ki` is used to specifically mean `1024` instead but that's not always the case especially in older interfaces.

If you keep that in mind and look at the size again you'll find that `9768` is exactly the size you allocated in KiB rounded to the nearest multiple of a page size (commonly 4KiB): `10,000,000 / 1024 = 9765.625` which rounds to `9768`.

The difference in pointer `7ff9cf753000` vs `7ff9cf753010` is the bookkeeping header `malloc` uses, which you blamed the missing bytes on.